# Couldn't find Song with id=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When trying to edit a song I get the **following error:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SongsController#show
Couldn't find Song with id=edit
Extracted source (around line #69):


def set_song
@song = Song.find(params[:id])
end
def song_params
```

For access to the code-base/easy troubleshooting see: www.github.com/apane/leap

For what it's worth I've just installed and got CanCan working but unfortunetly, I've been hit with the above error subsequently.

**song (resources) routes:**

```
 songs GET    /songs(.:format)               songs#index
                         POST   /songs(.:format)               songs#create
                new_song GET    /songs/new(.:format)           songs#new
               edit_song GET    /songs/:id/edit(.:format)      songs#edit
                    song GET    /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#show
                         PATCH  /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#update
                         PUT    /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#update
                         DELETE /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#destroy
             songs_index GET    /songs/index(.:format)         songs#index
              songs_show GET    /songs/show(.:format)          songs#show
               songs_new GET    /songs/new(.:format)           songs#new
              songs_edit GET    /songs/edit(.:format)          songs#edit
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)             songs#contact
                     faq GET    /faq(.:format)                 songs#faq
                    root GET    /                              songs#index
```

Comment: assuming error for routing. can u show ur routes for songs resources?

Comment: sure! i've added them above

Comment: @Debadatt The routes file can be found in [github repo](https://github.com/Apane/leap/blob/master/config/routes.rb).

Comment: You have a routing conflict because you have `GET /songs/:id` ahead of `GET /songs/edit`.  When you request `GET /songs/edit` the first filter will pick it up, and will treat `edit` as the `:id` parameter, which is why you're seeing the error where it's trying to find a `Song` with `id=edit`.  Can you share your actual `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **songs/index.html.erb** view you have:

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(@song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, @song %>
<% end %>
```

link should be:

```
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, song %>
```

`song` not `@song`

and in routes.rb

if you have:

```
resources :songs
```

you don't need:

```
  get "songs/index"
  get "songs/show"
  get "songs/new"
  get "songs/edit"
```

Comment: Good catch. But wouldn't this throw a `NoMethodError` instead of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a routing conflict:

```
resources :songs

get "songs/index"
get "songs/show"
get "songs/new"
get "songs/edit"
```

I'm guessing that you received the error when trying to follow the `songs/edit` path. Well, the `resources :songs` declaration above it overrides it, calling `show` with the id `"path"`, matching the error message.

Delete all of those `get` declarations because they are unnecessary;  `resources :songs` overrides them with RESTful routes.

Comment: thanks my man, just tried it but unfortunately i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What path/URL are you trying to access?

Comment: this is the path: <%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(@song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, @song %>

Comment: see magnum2002's answer.